# Python: How to manage multiple user?

Tags: python, json, database, file, dictionary

I have a list of users IDs and each user ID has a lot of friends IDs. I want to write a program to send message to user's friend.  So how to manage these information ? I think I should using 1 single file and write this Json format into file:

```
{'id_user':1, 'id_friend': 123}
{'id_user':1, 'id_friend': 124}
{'id_user':1, 'id_friend': 125}
{'id_user':1, 'id_friend': 126}
{'id_user':2, 'id_friend': 222}
{'id_user':2, 'id_friend': 223}
{'id_user':2, 'id_friend': 224}
{'id_user':2, 'id_friend': 225} 
...
```

If i use this way, after that, the file will have few dozen million rows.
So, What is best way to manage these users ? What type of database I should use ?  Thank you !

Comment: use relation database for that, like postgresql or mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my answer is not too biased...

Depending on what else you want to accomplish, there are several options:

- In standard library you have [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) which is a relational database engine (which can handle large amounts of rows quite well)
- There are other relational database engines like mysql for which python libraries exist (most have better performance for huge datasets that sqlite)
- There is [ZODB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB) (tutorial on [zodb.org](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/)) which is an object-database engine (you can actually use it as an ORM, too)
- There are object-relational mappers (ORM) like [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or the one included in [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) that can help you build databases.

You should have a look at the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseProgramming/) which providess deeper info about that